# Network I/O and Disk I/O without installing anything or using third parties libraries

Tags: linux, shell-script, statistics

I can't find anything on how can I get the network I/O and disk I/O without installing any libraries on my server.

I tried with this for the disk I/O:

```
cut -d" " -f 1,2,42 /proc/*/stat | sort -n -k +3
```

And for network I/O I was thinking on parsing `/proc/net/dev`.

But I don't find a way to get this information.

Comment: Look at the `iostat` and `netstat` commands.

Comment: Both are external libraries. I want to do this without using/installing third parties libraries

Comment: What is a third-party library to you? If you're on Solaris, where the distinction is meaningful, `iostat` at least is part of the system. With Linux, would first-party include the kernel and `git` (i.e. stuff by Linus Torvalds), but not things like `ls` or `bash` (i.e. stuff by GNU)? The inverse of that? The collection of all things included in a base install of the distribution? If the latter, which distribution?

Comment: `iostat` and `netstat` are _not_ libraries; they are binaries.  They may or may not be linked against shared objects (aka libraries).  The correct answer to this question seems to be "only install binaries that are statically linked".

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions generally install the very basics and you extend functionality with packages. Using Gnu tools is not an external library. However if you do not wish to install anything you can use C and use the Linux interfaces directly.